# Exporting functions as a library

Tags: python, function

I have the following question which asks me to write a library of functions. I've managed to write the functions, but I'm not sure how to package them into a library. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Write a short library of functions in Python. Each should be an individual function, and should be able to,
•   Sort numbers and return values in order
•   Determine whether a number is an integer
•   Determine whether a number is a negative
•   Determine if an input is a number
Each should take 1 input, and return 1 output

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) will help

Comment: I suspect that you are overthinking the word "library" here and that a simple module (code file) containing the function definitions is what the instructor means. If so, no real packaging is required.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have to publish your code somewhere, a program could act as a library in a way.

You could save your functions in a simple python file, say `functions.py`.

Then, in another python program (say `main.py`), you can import your functions, just like a library:

`from functions import *`.

Now you have access to all the functions you wrote.